# Map and Location Settings fails to deploy to scratch org

Tags: scratch-org, scratch-org-definition-file

When attempting to create a scratch org with [Map Settings](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.242.0.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_mapandlocationsettings.htm) turned on, I get the following error:

"The object 'MapAndLocation' of type Settings metadata does not exist."

However, the scratch definition appears correct and I can enable those settings in the org itself. It's the same if I switch the booleans to false.

```
{
  "orgName": "Development Org",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": [...],
  "settings": {
    ...
    "mapAndLocationSettings": {
      "enableMapsAndLocation": true,
      "enableAddressAutoComplete": true
    }
    ...
  }
}
```

Any ideas what's going on here? Has anyone been able to successfully turn those features on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct setting for the scratch definition file is `mapsAndLocationSettings`. (Maps not map)

However, if you do correct this, you will still get an error. Maps and Location Services are only available in Professional, Enterprise, Performance, and Unlimited edition orgs. Scratch orgs are Developer Edition orgs.

See https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?language=en_US&id=sf.customize_maps.htm&type=5